# Issue with jQuery Isotope and loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Here's the dev site in question:
http://dev.digitalskydesign.com/portfolio/

I'm using the latest version of Isotope and jQuery. The issue arises when I load this page. Sometimes when you load it you'll see everything line up neat and organized. Other times when you re-load it, you'll see some of the images overlapping each other or showing up completely out of place.

I'm not sure what the issue is.

Here's the code I'm using to initialize the Isotope (this is called in my themes functions.js file):

```
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
// options
});
// filter items on button click
$('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

Any thoughts? Clearly something is up, but the answer seems to allude me.